# Custom Tag Helper How to set the id and name in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I was playing a bit with MVC core and trying to do some common use cases. 
I wonder how could I implement the following scenario.
So I would like to implement a custom tag helper element that could identify when the element is from a list, to set the element name and id with the correspondent prefix array.
I realised that it does well with an element using the attribute `asp-for`,
So how could I get the same result implementing a custom Tag helper.

**Custom Tag Helper**

```
private const string selectEnumValue = "value";

[HtmlAttributeName(selectEnumValue)]
public ModelExpression SelectEnumValue { get; set; }

public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = "select";
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", SelectEnumValue.Metadata.PropertyName);
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("name", SelectEnumValue.Metadata.PropertyName);
    output.Content.AppendHtml(Options());
}
```

**Razor Example**

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.List.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td><select-enum value="List[i].AboutType"></select-enum></td>
        <td><select-bool value="List[i].IsActive"></select-bool></td>
        <td><lookup value="List[i].AboutId" text="List[i].AboutText" url="About">Test</lookup></td>
        <td><input asp-for="List[i].StartDate" class="date form-control" /></td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Result using asp-for**

```
<input class="date form-control" type="datetime-local" data-val="true" data-val-required="The StartDate field is required." id="List_0__StartDate" name="List[0].StartDate" value="2018-04-03T14:23:25.791">
```

**Result using the custom tag helper**

```
<select id="AboutType" name="AboutType"><option value="">Select...</option><option selected="" value="1">Test</option><option value="2">Hey</option></select>
```

So my question is how can I implement the tag helper to set an id with the same structure as the `asp-for`, so this element id and name would look like `id="List_0__AboutType"` and `name="List[0].AboutType"`

Answer (score 1):

For the id attribute, this helpful article worked for me :
http://blog.techdominator.com/article/using-html-helper-inside-tag-helpers.html

You will have to use a ModelExpression property as mentionned previously, eg.:

```
public ModelExpression AspFor { get; set; }
```

(the property "AspFor" will be available as "asp-for" attribute due to casing)

Then, inject the HtmlHelper in your ctor :

```
    private IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    public MyCustomTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
    }
```

Add the property :

```
    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

Initialize contextualize the HtmlHelper and use it to generate a sanitized Id from the ModelExpression.Name :

```
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        (_htmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);
        var id = _htmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(AspFor.Name);
```

...

Answer (score -1):

The solution is as easy as passing the ModelExpression name `(SelectEnumValue.Name)`.

```
private const string selectEnumValue = "value";

[HtmlAttributeName(selectEnumValue)]
public ModelExpression SelectEnumValue { get; set; }

public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = "select";
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", SelectEnumValue.Name);
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute("name", SelectEnumValue.Name);
    output.Content.AppendHtml(Options());
}
```

Comment: If you have a Razor Page you might see this on the page: `<input name='Input.Email' id='Input_Email' />`. The `ModelExpression.Name` value has the "dot" syntax, so it probably works for the `name` attribute. But the OP asked about getting the `id` attribute value, which uses "underscore" syntax.